# MySQL - Selecting data from three different tables

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I'm trying to select data from three different tables. How would I go about joining these tables to make the proper query?

```
****customers****
--------------------------
id            full_name
54            Matt Damon
53            Jimmy Kimmel

****samples****
--------------------------
id            rma_id
57            USARP011315-25
56            USARP011315-24

****early_ships****
--------------------------
customer_id   sample_id   shipping_carrier
54            57          UPS
53            56          FedEx
```

This is the query I've been running but I've yielded 0 results. This is the tutorial I've been following: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-join-three-tables-in-sql-query-mysql-sqlserver.html

```
SELECT samples.rma_id, customers.full_name, early_ships.shipping_carrier, 
FROM customers c JOIN early_ships e ON c.id = e.customer_id
JOIN samples s ON e.sample_id = s.id
```

Comment: can you tell what is the result that you want from this three table ?

Comment: That looks fine to me. I don't suppose it's the extra comma at the end of the first line?

Comment: show us the real query if above is not the one...

Comment: I wanted to grab both rows from each table above. The problem is fixed once I changed the original names to the table alias I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. There's an extra comma at the end of the SELECT clause.
2. In the FROM..JOIN clause, you've given nicknames, but then you're trying to use the original names in the SELECT clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT s.rma_id, c.full_name, e.shipping_carrier

FROM customers c
JOIN early_ships e
    ON c.id = e.customer_id
JOIN samples s
    ON e.sample_id = s.id
```

(whitespace added for readability)

Comment: for SQL aliases, once I create an alias I'm assuming I cannot use the original name anymore then correct?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the table aliases in the `SELECT` clause. Please check this fiddle I created for you. It's working perfectly. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49462/8